# How did Lightroom automatically find location of files after moving to a different partition?

Tags: lightroom, file-management, windows, lightroom-catalog

I moved my photos and Lightroom catalog files to a different partition on my hard drive and then opened Lightroom expecting to have point Lightroom to the new location of the image files and catalog.

However on first open Lightroom has already found all the files in their new location, there is nothing missing.

Everything I have read says that after moving the files I would have to find the missing files in Lightroom , so how did Lightroom find them automatically?

Before the move they were in the Windows 'My photos' folder and I instructed Windows that the 'my photos' folder is now on the partition, but the file path is still completely different from before so interested how Lightroom found the location.

Comment: "My photos" had two paths - one real and one as a ssymlinc.  So I think that Lightroom is using the symbolic link path.

Comment: Yes, this sounds likely.

Comment: @Alex.S your comment sounds more likely than my answer. I would create an answer to that effect

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Lightroom uses a `relative path` to the files in order to retrieve them. The path will be relative to the catalogue location. Eg, if the catalogue is in a `catalogues` folder, and alongside the `catalogues` folder are dated pictures folders (eg `2016-08-15`), then it knows that to get to a picture on a particular date, from the location of the active catalogue, it has to go `up one level`, and then down a level into the appropriate folder.

This path is still the same, as long as the folder containing `catalogues` and the dated image folders is moved in its entirety

Comment: The old location was: C:\Users\Max\Pictures

The new locations is: D:\Max\Pictures

Although I didn't tell Lighroom where the catalog had moved to either (same folder above), it just found everything on start up.

Comment: When you use the default Windows 'Pictures' folder, does it point to the pictures folder on the D: drive (and doesn't just have it as a search location)? In which case, it's probably using the symbolic link as per @Alex.S comment to your question. When you open the catalogue though, do you open the Lightroom application as opposed to double clicking on the Catalogue file? Note also that in Windows, if you're using a shortcut to the actual catalogue file, if the catalogue file gets moved, I think Windows will update the destination path of the shortcut